# Partition and process SSAS cube for huge data

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, partitioning, olap-cube

I've a SSAS cube with rigid relationship. Daily I get data from source for last 2 months only. My cube have data since 2010 onwards.
I am planning to partition that cube and then process it. My questions are

1. I know that in rigid relationship I've to go with Process full. Does that mean that I've to process all partition as Process Full or I can go ahead with selected partition for process full.
2. How can I design my partition strategy? If I do 2 months partition then I will end up in 6 partition per year and later they may  increase. I thought of going with 6 months partition. but if I am on 7th month or 1st month then I've to process two partition(i.e. current + last 6 month). Is it good enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marking attribute relationships as Rigid when they actually do change (meaning when the rollups change such as Product A rolling up to Cereal vs. Oatmeal category) is a bad idea. Just mark them as Flexible relationships. Rigid vs. flexible doesn't impact query performance just processing performance. And if Rigid causes you to do ProcessFull on dimensions that is going to mean you have to reprocess all your measure group partitions. So change relationships to Flexible unless you are 100% sure you never run an UPDATE statement on your dimension table in your ETL.

I would partition by month. Then you can just process the most recent two months every day. To be more explicit:

1. ProcessUpdate your dimensions
2. ProcessData the most recent two months of partitions.
3. ProcessIndexes on your cube (which rebuilds indexes and flexible aggs on older partitions)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately, we have many relationship which is identified as rigid as per business and we can not change that now(ex: Demographic, Date, BusinessProcesss etc). However, I have to continue like that, does mean that I have to go with ProcessFull the database even if I have measure group partition? The steps which you have mentioned is related to rigid relationship or for flexible?

Comment: Rigid is just an optimization. I would not every try to enforce a business rule with that property. Let the business tell you that demographic data "should" never change but then you validate it against what's actually happening in the ETL. If it does change then don't let the business dictate technology. Explain to them that it did change and here is an example. And change the relationship to Flexible.

Comment: In practice I see Rigid only ever used on Date dimensions that are literally hardcoded. Use Flexible and ProcessUpdate. Do not use Rigid and ProcessFull as that totally invalidates the purpose of the optimization

Comment: Just to be clear, you can do ProcessUpdate on a dimension with Rigid relationships. It will succeed if the data behind the relationships hasn't changed. If it fails then the data changed and the relationship should not be marked Rigid.

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense to me. +1 for explaining in detail